# Run time error 2107 after running a "DELETE .." SQL statement - VBA/MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error

I am relatively new to Access VBA and I keep getting the run-time error 2107 on every even numbered run of the following code, and every odd numbered run runs very fine.

I have a summary form that is built to find unique course names and perform a mathematical count function according to filter criteria given by the user. The results are temporarily stored in a table Tbl_EnqSummary.

The code goes like this:

```
'Empty all previous records in the EnqSummary table:
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM Tbl_EnqSummary"

'find out unique entries in the main data table (Enquiries) and populate the Courseidentifier field in the EnqSummary table with these distinct names:
courses = "INSERT INTO Tbl_EnqSummary ( CourseIdentifier ) " _
                & "SELECT DISTINCT Tbl_Enquiries.CourseEnquiryIdentifier FROM Tbl_Enquiries " _
            & "WHERE ((Tbl_Enquiries.EnqDate >= #" & Format(Me.txtDateFrom.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#) " _
            & "AND (Tbl_Enquiries.EnqDate <= #" & Format(Me.txtDateTo.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#)) " _
                & "ORDER BY Tbl_Enquiries.CourseEnquiryIdentifier"

'Requery the form
DoCmd.RunSQL courses
summarytable = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_EnqSummary ORDER BY Tbl_EnqSummary.CourseIdentifier"
Me.RecordSource = summarytable
Me.AllowAdditions = False
Me.Requery
```

Here I get the run-time error 2107 stating there is some validation rule being violated. There is no validation rule anywhere - I have checked and checked.

Comment: Is the error triggered with the INSERT?

Comment: Which line is causing the error? 
what is the type of Tbl_Enquiries.CourseEnquiryIdentifier ? of Tbl_EnqSummary.CourseIdentifier?

Comment: The error was triggered after the DELETE sql statement as well as the INSERT statement on every even run of the code. So the code runs correctly in the first run, but gives an error on second run, and then runs correctly on the third run.

Comment: Tbl_Enquiries.CourseEnquiryIdentifier is a text field, as is the Tbl_EnqSummary.CourseIndetifier

Comment: I changed the DELETE sql to read "DELETE FROM Tbl_EnqSummary" and removed the *. Now its giving the 3167 error - Record is deleted. Again odd runs are running good, even runs generate the error.